# Wordpress custom rewrite rule breaks normal posts view

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to add a custom rewrite rule in wordpress using the rewrite api through a custom plugin. Unfortunately, after activating the plugin, I am no more able to view/preview normal posts.  Here is the code for my plugin

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: URL Rewrite Test
 */
add_action('init', 'z_add_rewrite_rules');

function z_add_rewrite_rules(){
    add_rewrite_rule('^ztest/([a-z0-9-]+)[/]?$','index.php?ztest=$matches[1]','top');
}

add_filter('query_vars','z_set_query_vars');

function z_set_query_vars(){
    $query_vars[] = 'ztest';
    return $query_vars;
}

add_filter('template_include','z_include_template');

function z_include_template(){
    if(get_query_var('ztest')){
        //path to template file
        $new_template = plugin_dir_path(__FILE__).'/template.php';
        if(file_exists($new_template)){
            $template = $new_template;
        }
    }    
    return $template;
}

?>
```

template.php

```
<h1>Ztest</h1>
```

When I try to browse `localhost:81/wordpress572/hello-world/` , all I see is a blank page while browsing `localhost:81/wordpress572/ztest/asdf/`, I am able to see the page with `Ztest` h1.
I am able to view the normal posts after deactivating the plugin.

Note: I have set the permalinks to Post name in permalinks settings.

Answer (score 0):

The following modification to my code fixed the problem but I am not pretty sure why was the template_include even called for this url.

```
function z_include_template($original_template){
    if(get_query_var('ztest')){
        //path to template file
        $new_template = plugin_dir_path(__FILE__).'/template.php';
        if(file_exists($new_template)){
            $template = $new_template;
        }
    } else {
        $template = $original_template;
    }    
    return $template;
}
```